# NASM: Trying to add 2 variables

Tags: variables, addition, nasm, system-calls

```
global _start

section .data

section .bss     ;declares 3 variables
num1:   resb 4
num2:   resb 4
sum:    resb 4
section .text

_start:
mov     ecx, num1
mov     edx, 02h

call        read
call        write

mov     ecx, num2
mov     edx, 02h

call        read2
call        write2

;mov        ecx, sum
;mov        edx, 02h

mov     ecx, num1
add     ecx, num2
mov     sum, ecx

je      exit

exit:   ;exits the program
mov     eax, 01h        ; exit()
xor     ebx, ebx        ; errno
int     80h

read:   ;reads input from the keyboard and stores it in ecx
mov     eax, 03h        ; read()
mov     ebx, 00h        ; stdin
mov     ecx, num1
int     80h
ret

read2:   ;reads input from the keyboard and stores it in ecx
mov     eax, 03h        ; read()
mov     ebx, 00h        ; stdin
mov     ecx, num2
int     80h
ret

write:   ;outputs the contents of ecx to stdout
mov     eax, 04h        ; write()
mov     ebx, 01h        ; stdout
mov     ecx, num1
int     80h
ret

write2:   ;outputs the contents of ecx to stdout
mov     eax, 04h        ; write()
mov     ebx, 01h        ; stdout
mov     ecx, num2
int     80h
ret
```

I need help with adding the 2 variables together. I keep receiving `invalid combination of opcode and operands` errors from the line    `mov     sum, ecx`. It feels like I've tried dozens of combinations with no real luck. Once I get the variables added to the sum variable I will also need to print the result to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you are trying to move ecx to immediate operand which is impossible.

```
mov     ecx, num1 ; num1 is the address of the "num1" label
add     ecx, num2 ; num2 is the address of the "num2" label
mov     sum, ecx  ; sum is the address of the "sum" label
```

So depending on the address of the labels, your code translates to something like:

```
mov     ecx, 0x401800
add     ecx, 0x401804
mov     0x401808, ecx
```

... which you probably don't want.
You have to use square brackets if you want to use the contents in the address:

```
mov     ecx, [num1] ; get contents at "num1"
add     ecx, [num2] ; get contents at "num2"
mov     [sum], ecx  ; move ecx to address "sum"
```